# Запись в текстовый файл

Tags: c#

Записываю получаемые значение `href` в текстовый файл. Месседж бокс их показывает корректно все до одного. Но в файл записывается только последнее значение и все. Я добавил `Environment.NewLine`, но это ничего не поменяло.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test.txt");

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
    sw.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value + Environment.NewLine);
    sw.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в цикле закрываете поток. По идее, в файл должно попадать только 1 значение, а потом исключение должно появиться

```
sw.Close();
```

Вот такой код работает

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.txt");

        string[] st = new string[] {"fff", "aaa", "kkk"};

        foreach (var node in st)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(node);
            sw.WriteLine(node + Environment.NewLine);
            //sw.Close();
        }

        sw.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

В конце поток обязательно надо закрыть. 
И еще: если вы используете дословную строку (начинается с @), то писать так

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\Test.txt");
```

не обязательно. можно просто

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.txt");
```

один "\" вместо "\\"

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!

Comment: @shatoidil пожалуйста

Comment: using надо использовать, а не Close.

Answer (score 4):

Мне больше нравится такой код:

```
using (var sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Test.txt"))
{
      sw.WriteLine("строка с данными");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вы поток после каждой итерации закрываете? У вас не просто записвается только одно значение, а еще и вываливается исключение после обращения к  уже освобожденному поток. Перенесите sw.Close() за пределы цикла и будет вам счастье. Плюс еще уберите NewLine, тем самым вы только добавляете лишний разрыв строки. 
Ну и еще крайне не советовал бы писать Close без try/finally или using

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы реально писал не последний взятый текст в файл, а все, код нужно изменить:`

```
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\Test.txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.Default)) {

        sw.WriteLine(eventArgs.EventId.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);             

   }`
```

Нужен второй параметр true  для Append