# Не записывает информацию в уже существующий текстовый файл

Tags: c#

Существует текстовый файл,в который нужно дописать полученные в ходе работы программы результаты(при этом не очищая файл от информации,которая внутри него)

Что делает код,представленный ниже
Для начала проверка чтобы `textbox`-ы были не пустыми,если не пустые то их значения записываются в переменные `kef` и `emp` 
После создаётся `StreamWriter`с указанием в какой файл нужно записать 
С помощью команды `strw.Write` планируется дописать в уже существующий файл 2 строки с 2-мя переменными `kef` и `emp`

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text!="" && textBox5.Text!="") 
    {
    double kef = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    double emp = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
    StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter("kendal.txt", true);
    strw.Write("Коэффициент корреляции Кенделла= ", kef, Environment.NewLine);
    strw.Write("Эмпирическое значение = ", emp, Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show("Сохранение выполнено!");
    strw.Close();
    }
    else 
    MessageBox.Show("Вычисление не выполнено!Сохранение невозможно");
}
```

В итоге в файл ничего не записывается,но и ничего не удаляется(а вот это хорошо)

**PS**
На эту тематику были найдены вопросы,например как этот
[Запись в текстовый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419294/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Но разница в том что в моём случае немного проще,так как нужно дописать значения с `textBox`, которые уже известны.

Comment: А сам файл, который ты хочешь дописать где лежит? Я к тому, что в коде явно задано, что перезапись идет в файл, который находится в директории с Exe-файлом.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вот его путь `labwork2:\bin\Debug\kendal.txt `

Да он в директории проекта

Comment: Оберните `StreamWriter` в `using` и внутри этого блока делайте запись,  `strw.Close();` уберите. Из файла ничего не удаляется, так как второй параметр `true` указывает, что  данные будут добавлены в файл без перезаписи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text != "" && textBox5.Text != "") 
    {
        double kef = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        double emp = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);

        using (StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter("kendal.txt", true))
        {
            strw.WriteLine("Коэффициент корреляции Кенделла = " + kef);
            strw.WriteLine("Эмпирическое значение = " + emp);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Сохранение выполнено!");           
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Вычисление не выполнено!Сохранение невозможно");
    }

}
```

Вместо метода `Write` совместно с [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) используйте `WriteLine`, а также оберните `StreamWriter` в `using`.

Answer (score 1):

### Запись в уже существующий каталог

```
using (StreamWriter fileW =                                // создаем поток записи
                    new StreamWriter(@"File.txt", true))   // Открываем файл для записи в конец
                    {
                        fileW.WriteLine("Stackoverflow");  // Сама запись
                    }
```

*Надеюсь помог!*